# Couldn't decompress package - Robot lab

Tags: import, unity-game-engine, package

I am working in Unity 3D.

I tried to import Robot Lab, but I got an error: "Couldn't decompress package". What to do?

With best regards,

proggamer12

Comment: The package is probably corrupted. Have you tried re-downloading it?

Comment: The package is too big for me to redownload. But I will try. Thanks!